# Make a Swift 5 function with completionHandler to print JSON data

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

I have the following Swift 5 function that calls a PHP script on my server:

```
func getJSONdata(fileName:String, completion: (_ json:JSON)->()) {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
        var jsonData = JSON()

        let myUrl = URL(string: DATABASE_PATH + fileName + "/query.php?queryAll");
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error)  in
                if error != nil {
                    print("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }

                // Get data
                jsonData = try! JSON(data: data!)
                // print(jsonData)
            }
            task.resume()
        }//  ./ dispatch aync
        completion(jsonData)
    }
```

This function is hosted in a separate Swift file, now in my **ViewController.swift** I call that function as follows:

```
getJSONdata(fileName: "Users") { (jsonData) in
    print("\(jsonData)")
}
```

In this case, I'm getting an empty array in my Xcode console, instead, if I uncomment the `// print(jsonData)` that's inside my `getJSONdata()` function, the console prints out my JSON data.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong in my `getJSONdata()` function because I cannot retrieve data by calling in **ViewController.swift**.

Where is the error in my function?

Comment: what happens if you move `completion(jsonData)` under `jsonData = try! JSON(data: data!)`

Comment: you should call the completion handler after you will get a response/data from API.

Comment: Ok, but this is what I get: https://i.postimg.cc/g0gz2wvy/error.png

Comment: Thanks @chirag90, you're right, I also had to add **@escaping** to my function's declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. Maybe it will help you.

```
func getJSONdata(fileName:String, completion:@escaping (_ json:JSON)->()) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
            var jsonData = JSON()

            let myUrl = URL(string: DATABASE_PATH + fileName + "/query.php?queryAll");
            var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error)  in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                        completion(nil)
                    }

                    // Get data
                    jsonData = try! JSON(data: data!)
                    // print(jsonData)
                    completion(jsonData)
                }
                task.resume()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason, it doesn't work, as shown here: https://i.postimg.cc/g0gz2wvy/error.png. Anyway, I've posted an answer which is the solutoin to my issue, hope it helps other ones.

Comment: Anyway, I had updated my answer. Please check if you've any queries.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, I don't know why but if I add `@escaping` to my function declaration, it works fine.

I also had to move `completion(jsonData)` below `jsonData = try! JSON(data: data!)`, as suggested by @chirag90.

So, here's the complete function:

```
func getJSONdata(fileName:String, completion: @escaping (_ json:JSON?) -> Void) {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
        var jsonData = JSON()

        let myUrl = URL(string: DATABASE_PATH + fileName + "/query.php?queryAll");
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error)  in
                if error != nil {
                    self.simpleAlert("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }

                // Get data
                jsonData = try! JSON(data: data!)
                completion(jsonData)
            }
            task.resume()
        }//  ./ dispatch aync
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will, but I can do that only in 2 days, not now :)

Comment: Don’t  use SwiftyJSON. Take a looks at Codable protocol

Comment: Why shouldn't I use SwiftyJSON? It makes me save tons of lines of code